# Set new path to Wordpress logo

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I want to change the URL path when clicked on the logo. I tried changing the direction but it didn't work.

```
    <?php

//set logo path
$logo_path = sq_option_url( 'logo' );
$logo_path = apply_filters( 'kleo_logo', $logo_path );
$social_icons = apply_filters( 'kleo_show_social_icons', sq_option( 'show_social_icons', 1 ) );
$top_bar = sq_option( 'show_top_bar', 1 );
$top_bar = apply_filters( 'kleo_show_top_bar', $top_bar );

$top_menu = wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'    => 'top',
        'depth'             => 2,
        'container'         => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'top-menu col-sm-12 col-md-7 no-padd',
        'menu_class'        => '',
        'fallback_cb'       => '',
        'walker'            => new kleo_walker_nav_menu(),
        'echo'              => false
    )
);

$primary_menu = wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 3,
        'container'         => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse nav-collapse',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
        //'fallback_cb'       => 'kleo_walker_nav_menu::fallback',
        'fallback_cb'       => '',
        'walker'            => new kleo_walker_nav_menu(),
        'echo'              => false
    )
);

?>

<div id="header" class="header-color">

    <div class="navbar" role="navigation">

        <?php if ($top_bar == 1) { //top bar enabled ?>

        <!--Attributes-->
        <!--class = social-header inverse-->
        <div class="social-header header-color">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="top-bar">

                <div id="top-social" class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 no-padd">
                    <?php echo kleo_get_social_profiles(); ?>
                </div>

                <?php
                // Top menu
                echo $top_menu;
                ?>

            </div><!--end top-bar-->
        </div>
            </div>

            <?php } //end top bar condition ?>

            <?php
            $header_style = sq_option( 'header_layout', 'normal' );
            if ( $header_style == 'right_logo' ) {
                $header_class = ' logo-to-right';
            } elseif ( $header_style == 'center_logo' ) {
                $header_class = ' header-centered';
            } elseif ( $header_style == 'left_logo' ) {
                $header_class = ' header-left';
            } else {
                $header_class = ' header-normal';
            }
            ?>
            <div class="kleo-main-header<?php echo $header_class;?>">
                <div class="container">   
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <div class="kleo-mobile-switch">

                            <?php
                            $mobile_menu_atts = 'class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"';
                            /* open the Side menu instead of the normal menu */
                            if ( sq_option( 'side_menu_mobile', 0 ) == 1 ) {
                                $mobile_menu_atts = 'class="navbar-toggle open-sidebar"';
                            }
                            ?>
                            <button type="button" <?php echo $mobile_menu_atts;?>>
                                <span class="sr-only"><?php _e("Toggle navigation",'kleo_framework');?></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>

                        </div>

                        <div class="kleo-mobile-icons">

                            <?php 
                            /** kleo_mobile_header_icons - action
                             * You can put here various icons using this action
                             *
                             * @hooked kleo_bp_mobile_notify - 9
                             * @hooked kleo_woo_mobile_icon - 10
                             */
                            do_action( 'kleo_mobile_header_icons' );
                            ?>

                        </div>

                        <strong class="logo">
                            <a href="http://hpkursen.se/hem/">
                                <?php if ($logo_path != '') { ?>

                                    <img id="logo_img" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" src="<?php echo $logo_path; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">

                                <?php } else { ?>

                                    <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>

                                <?php } ?>

                            </a>
                        </strong>
                    </div>

                    <?php if ($header_style == 'left_logo') : ?>
                    <div class="header-banner">
                        <?php echo do_shortcode( sq_option( 'header_banner', '' ) );?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <?php
                    // Main menu
                    echo $primary_menu;
                    ?>
                </div><!--end container-->
            </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

The URL I want to redirect to instead of home is **hpkursen.se/hem/**
I tried to change the `<a href="<?php echo home_url();?>">` to `<a href="http://hpkursen.se/hem/">` but it still redirects to the Homepage when clicked. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Does it change to `<a href="http://hpkursen.se/hem/">`  in the source code when the page is rendered?

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer to your question:

Use `<a href="<?php echo home_url();?>/hem/"`> and it should work.

For more details/examples, please visit: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url

**EDIT**

I connected to your website and it seems that you're not editing the right file :) . You have this piece of code: `$header_style = sq_option( 'header_layout', 'normal' );`

Search for the file "header_layout". Search for this in your files:

```
<header>
<a class="logo" style="width:395px" href="http://hpkursen.se" rel="home">
<img alt="logo" src="http://hpkursen.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo_org_b.png">
</a>
</header>
```

Make sure you opened the right header file!

**EDIT 2**

There are two options:

**1. Edit plugin**

Go to: wp-content/plugins/maintenance/load/functions.php

On the line 155 you will find this:

```
function get_logo_box() {
        $mt_options = mt_get_plugin_options(true);
        $out_html = '';

            if ( !empty($mt_options['logo']) ) { 
                $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $mt_options['logo'], 'full'); 
                $out_html = '<a class="logo" rel="home" href="'.esc_url(site_url('')) .'" style="width:'.$logo[1].'px">';
                    $out_html .= '<img src="'. esc_url($logo[0]) .'" alt="logo"/>';
                $out_html .= '</a>'; 
            } else { 
                $out_html = '<a class="logo istext" rel="home" href="'.esc_url(site_url('')) .'">';
                    $out_html .= '<h1 class="site-title">'. get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .'</h1>';
            } 
            $out_html .= '</a>'; 

        echo $out_html;
    }
    add_action ('logo_box', 'get_logo_box', 10);
```

Replace it with:

```
function get_logo_box() {
        $mt_options = mt_get_plugin_options(true);
        $out_html = '';

            if ( !empty($mt_options['logo']) ) { 
                $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $mt_options['logo'], 'full'); 
                $out_html = '<a class="logo" rel="home" href="'.esc_url(site_url('/hem/')) .'" style="width:'.$logo[1].'px">';
                    $out_html .= '<img src="'. esc_url($logo[0]) .'" alt="logo"/>';
                $out_html .= '</a>'; 
            } else { 
                $out_html = '<a class="logo istext" rel="home" href="'.esc_url(site_url('/hem/')) .'">';
                    $out_html .= '<h1 class="site-title">'. get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .'</h1>';
            } 
            $out_html .= '</a>'; 

        echo $out_html;
    }
    add_action ('logo_box', 'get_logo_box', 10);
```

What I did was replacing this line: `$out_html = '<a class="logo" rel="home" href="'.esc_url(site_url('/')) .'" style="width:'.$logo[1].'px">';`

with this line: `$out_html = '<a class="logo" rel="home" href="'.esc_url(site_url('/hem/')) .'" style="width:'.$logo[1].'px">';`

**2. Edit your theme's functions.php file**

Go to wp-content/themes/your theme and open the file: functions.php

At the end of this file add:

```
function get_logo_box() {
            $mt_options = mt_get_plugin_options(true);
            $out_html = '';

                if ( !empty($mt_options['logo']) ) { 
                    $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $mt_options['logo'], 'full'); 
                    $out_html = '<a class="logo" rel="home" href="'.esc_url(site_url('/hem/')) .'" style="width:'.$logo[1].'px">';
                        $out_html .= '<img src="'. esc_url($logo[0]) .'" alt="logo"/>';
                    $out_html .= '</a>'; 
                } else { 
                    $out_html = '<a class="logo istext" rel="home" href="'.esc_url(site_url('/hem/')) .'">';
                        $out_html .= '<h1 class="site-title">'. get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .'</h1>';
                } 
                $out_html .= '</a>'; 

            echo $out_html;
        }
        add_action ('logo_box', 'get_logo_box', 10);
```

In this way you will override the plugin's function.

Comment: Please refresh the browser using Ctrl + F5 or try another web browser if it's still not working.

Comment: I tried it and refreshed the browser but it still redirects to the Homepage when clicked.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code where you display the Logo. The a href and the logo display HTML/PHP code. I will be able to help you more.

Comment: I don't have the file "header_layout". I do have the file "header.php" and everything is PHP-code there is no HTML code

Comment: Ok, I've seen that you're using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/maintenance . Is it true? Because, if so, you will have to edit the plugin. I will tell you how, but first confirm me if I'm right.

Comment: I edited again my answer, see edit2. There are two options. Both should work.

Comment: Someone just downvoted me because I told him that his answer was bad :))